# Создание нового проекта Java Enterprise Intellij idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Всем привет!

Поставил самую новую версию Intellij idea ultimate, смотрю видеоуроки по java на ютубе, но есть проблема.
При создании нового проекта intellij idea отображает не такое стартовое окно как у людей с ютуба. Вкладка Java Enterprise отображается иначе и ее содержимое совсем другое.
Прикрепляю два скрина:
(качество второго скрина плохое, но это из-за того, что видео плохого качества)

[image: Как отображается у меня]

[image: Как отображается у человека с ютуба]

Ну и в общем-то я просто не могу выбрать сервер для приложения и поставить чекбокс "WebApp". Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Ну вроде проект и так будет "WebApp", а вот как настроить сервер: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-running-your-first-java-ee-application.html#glassfish

Comment: Это вопрос для службы поддержки, а не для SO.

Comment: Как минимум это полезная информация для сообщества программистов и с ней могут столкнуться многие из-за того, что проблема в новом обновлении idea, а не в каких-то моих настройках или ПК. И проще зайти на стак и увидеть готовый ответ, чем возиться пол дня с поддержкой

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У меня была установлена версия Ultimate IntelliJ IDEA 2020.2.3 x64.
Переустановил на более старую версию - 2020.1.4 и всё исправилось. В новых версиях изменили логику создания новых проектов